# should IMU frame follow the red-East, green-North and blue-Up convention?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming an IMU without abs yaw. The starting pose of the robot is always at 0 yaw. Isn't ENU frame where:
-Green axis points front(North) of vehicle
-Red axis points right(East) of vehicle
-Blue axis points up

I'm slightly confused since I see in the Jackal simulator that the imu_link frame is the same as base_link(red-x, green-y,blue-z):

[image: image description]

Here red points north, and green points west.
Am I just misunderstanding something? Can someone clear this up for me? I know the jackal should be using a ENU imu as well.

In my simulation I use hector_gazebo_plugin imu. Do I need to apply a transform(rpy) relative to baselink to indicate that the IMU is ENU?

```
  <joint name="IMU_FIXED" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.27876 -0.0014334 0.080087" rpy="0 3.1416 -1.5708" />
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="imu_link" />
  </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364998/should-imu-frame-follow-the-red-east,-green-north-and-blue-up-convention?/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> -Green axis points front(North) of vehicle -Red axis points right(East) of vehicle -Blue axis points up

No, "North" and "East" really mean "North" and "East" relative to the earth, not "front of vehicle" and "right of vehicle". The ENU convention means the following: If the device reports a neutral orientation (roll / pitch / yaw are all 0 in the `sensor_msgs/Imu` message), then the x axis (red) points East (relative to the earth), y (green) points North, and z points Up.

**Edited to add:** I just saw that you wrote that your IMU doesn't have absolute yaw. In that case, the x and y axis can point more or less into an arbitrary direction with respect to the earth (since the "zero yaw" position is also arbitrary with respect to the earth). To conform to the ENU convention, all that matters is that z points up. And of course the other fields in the `sensor_msgs/Imu` message are specified wrt. the coordinate axes; so x must point into the direction where `linear_acceleration.x` is positive and so on.

In any case, the ENU convention says nothing about how the IMU must be mounted on the vehicle.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4